# How to make selected item as active in sidebar in react js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I have a side bar. It contains Menus. Each Menu has sub menus.

1. Home
2. Menu1 ->1.submenu1
   ->submenu2
3. Menu2 -> sub1
   -> sub2
   On selecting the Menu, it should be in active(color:blue). Under that menu1, If we select submenu1 then its color should also be changed. On navigating to submenu1, Sidebar's submenu should not be closed. It should be opened. I have tried with different solutions, but couldn't fix.  Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance..

   ```
     <aside className="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <div className="sidebar">
                <nav>
                    <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar nav-child-indent flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                         <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to="/home" className="nav-link active">
                              <i className="nav-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                              <p>
                                Home
                              </p>
                            </Link>
                         </li>
                        <li className="nav-item has-treeview ">
                            <Link to="#" className="nav-link">
                              <i className="nav-icon fa fa-copy"></i>
                              <p>Menu1 <i className="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                              </p>
                            </Link>
                            <ul className="nav nav-treeview">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/submenu1" className="nav-link">
                                      <i className="fa fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                      <p>Submenu1</p>
                                    </a>
                                 </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/submenu2" className="nav-link">
                                      <i className="fa fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                      <p>Submenu2</p>
                                    </a>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item has-treeview">
                            <Link to="#" className="nav-link">
                              <i className="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
                              <p>Menu2 <i className="fa fa-angle-left right"></i>
                              </p>
                            </Link>
                            <ul className="nav nav-treeview">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/sub1" className="nav-link">
                                      <i className="fa fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                      <p>Sub1</p>
                                    </Link>
                                 </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link to="/sub2" className="nav-link">
                                      <i className="fa fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                      <p>Sub2</p>
                                    </Link>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </aside>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In React js, there are two components to navigate to a route:
`<NavLink>` and `<Link>`.

`<Link>` provides accessible navigation to your react application.

`<NavLink>` provides styling attributes to the rendered element if matches to the URL alongwith navigation. Some of the styling attributes are `activeClassName:String` and `activeStyle:Object`.

**Example of activeClassName attribute:**

```
<NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="selected">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="selected">About</NavLink>
```

And in CSS,

```
.selected {
   fontWeight: "bold",
   color: "red"
}
```

**Example of activeStyle:**

```
<NavLink to="/" exact activeStyles={{fontWeight: "bold", color: "red"}}>
Home
</NavLink>
```

Comment: It works for submenus. But I have menus with path as #.How to deal with it??

Comment: Replace # with / and write the exact param in the `<Navlink>`. You need to write the exact param two times in your program one with `<Navlink>` and another one with `<Route>`.  If a path like `/Home`, then react read as / + Home and the path of `/` will be routed instead of the path `/Home` only if the exact param is not set to the path `/`. That's why it is necessary to set exact param to the path `/`.